# ArrayList inside an ArrayList is getting overridden

Tags: java, arraylist

Here is my code.
In my case list is getting over ridden.
output should be [[1][1,1][1,2,1][1,3,3,1][1,4,6,4,1]
I am getting like - [[1, 4, 6, 4, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]]. which is latest value in the loop repeated. what might be the problem

```
int i,j;
i=0;
j=0;
int a;
Integer temp;
a = 5;
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for ( i =0 ;i<a ;i++)
{
    list1.clear();

    Integer number; 
    number = (int) Math.pow(11, i);
    LinkedList<Integer> stack = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    while (number > 0) {
        stack.push( number % 10 );
        number = number / 10;
    }

    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        temp = (stack.pop());
        list1.add(temp);    
    }
    list.add(list1);
}
System.out.println("The arraylist contains the following elements: "+ list);
```

Comment: Create a new instance of `list1` inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks it worked. list1.clear(); should do the same job right?

Comment: See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are cleaning your List1 array every time. And you have only one array list inside large array list. So you end up with the last results you put on inner arraylist. To get expected results, you shoud create several arraylists inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `list1.clear()` with `list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

In Java it is call by value. But when say `list1` you only have the **reference** to `list1`.

So when you are iterating, you are doing `list1.clear`. What it does it clears the list **pointed** to by the **reference list1**. This will clear the list that you added into the `list`. So what you get at the end is the latest content of `list1`.

For a detailed understanding, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)